# If $L: V\to V$ is a linear operator, and $V$ has bases of $n$ vectors, can we say rank$L = n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $L: V\to V$ is a linear mapping, and $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ and $\{L(v_1), ..., L(v_n)\}$ are bases for $V$, can we say that rank$L = n$ ?

I'm trying to prove that nullity$(L) = 0$, so my thought process is
since $V$ has a basis of $n$ vectors, dim$V = n$
if I can assume that rank$L = n$ too because $\{L(v_1), ..., L(v_n)\}$ is a basis of $V$ with $n$ vectors, then by rank nullity theorem the proof becomes trivial.

Comment: Could it be $\dim V < n$ and your bases are not linearly independent? You can certainly see that $\mathrm{rank} L \le n$...

Comment: by definition a basis is linearly independant though right?

Comment: not necessarily. Usually, a basis is a set which spans the space...

Comment: that's a spanning set. a basis is a linearly independent spanning set.

Comment: lots of books do not make the distinction, my linear algebra class didn't either -- it's a convention, but either way is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see that $\dim \operatorname{range}(L)\ge n$ because the range of $L$ contains a linearly independent set of $n$ vectors. Then because $\dim V=n$, we get $\operatorname{range}(L)=n$. So, $\operatorname{rk}(L)=n.$ Thus, by rank-nullity, $n=\operatorname{rk}(L)+\dim\operatorname{null}(L)=n+\dim\operatorname{null}(L).$ Hence, $\operatorname{null}(L)=\{0\}.$

Comment: can you please expand on how you get dim(range(L)) >= n? Also, its equal to n because dimV=n so by rank nullity (and considering nullity cannot be negative), dim(range(L)) = n?

Comment: The range of $L$ is a linear space, and the dimension of a linear space $X$ is equal to the maximal cardinality of a set of linearly independent vectors in $X$. So, because we have found at least $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\operatorname{range}(L)$, we see that it has dimension at least $n$. Then because $\dim V=n$, we get $n\le \dim\operatorname{rangle}(L)\le n$, hence $\dim\operatorname{rangle}(L)=n$.

Comment: do we get n <= dim(range(L)) <= n from the rank nullity theorem because nullity cant be <0?

Comment: No, that does not need the rank nullity theorem.

Comment: oh okay it just follows from the fact that the Range(L) is a subspace of V, so it cant have more than n vectors in its basis?

Comment: Yes, basically. $\dim\operatorname{range}(L)$ is bounded above by the dimension of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

The rank of $L$ is the dimension of its image so it is $dim(L)-dim(\ker(L))$. We will show that $\ker(L) = 0$, let $v\in V$ s.t. L(v)=0, then

$$0=L(v)=L\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iL(v_i)$$

Since the $L(v_i)$ form a basis we have $\lambda_i = 0$ for all $i$. Hence $v = 0$ and $\ker(L)=0$.

This implies $dim(L)= n$.

Comment: Ah this was my original approach, I wasn't sure if I could conclude from the fact that if any v in V means ker(L) = 0

Comment: This answer is correct too, but I am accepting the other one because it uses the approach mentioned in the original question. I upvoted you though.

Comment: No worries! You accept the one you were looking for.